# OpenSSL: Add Custom field with value as object to CSR

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, asn.1, csr

I want to add a custom object(JSON) attached to a custom field in CSR. The configuration file that I am using is

```
[req]
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions  = v3_req
prompt = no

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
keyUsage = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
subjectAltName = @alternate_names
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1=ASN1:UTF8String:"{"attrs":{"admin":"true","hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"user3","hf.Type":"client","myparam":"nitish"}}"

[alternate_names]
DNS.0 = SDK

[dn]
C="US"
ST="Illinois"
L="Chicago"
O="Some Company"
OU="peer"
0.OU="department1"
CN="12345"
```

Command:

```
openssl req -new -key user_pvt.key -out user.csr -config csr.conf -extensions v3_req
```

It successfully generates the CSR file. But, the **request extensions** has a *custom param* with value as **String**

```
Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                0F:F0:72:0A:1D:7E:79:98:04:CE:62:05:65:4B:41:C5:DE:9F:E7:55
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:SDK
            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                .h{attrs:{admin:true,hf.Affiliation:org1.department1,hf.EnrollmentID:user3,hf.Type:client,myparam:nitish}}
```

But, I need to add an Object to *1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1* as:

```
Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                0F:F0:72:0A:1D:7E:79:98:04:CE:62:05:65:4B:41:C5:DE:9F:E7:55
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:SDK
            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"admin":"true","hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"user3","hf.Type":"client","myparam":"nitish"}}
```

How do I add/specify this information in my csr.conf file to get this result?

**1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                    {"attrs":{"admin":"true","hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"user3","hf.Type":"client","myparam":"nitish"}}**

Comment: you need to escape double quotes in your JSON string. BTW: `CA:false` and `keyCertSign,cRLSign`???

Comment: Also FYI the `.h` at the beginning of the display is the tag and length octets of the UTF8STRING encoding and do not represent an error in the value. OpenSSL doesn't know the internal structure of nonstandard extensions, and doesn't try to decode them, even when they are simple like this one.

Comment: Did you find out how to remove this prefix?

Comment: Actually, I found out that because it's a custom implementation, one can use any notation as long as it meets the syntax of ASN1 extensions format. Fabric used 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1 as a key for adding custom parameters (being non-standard extension) in a digital certificate as it's easy to remember and it follows ASN1 standard.